# How to fix loading bar stopping before the end

Tags: python, processing

[i'm trying to make a loading bar but this is what came up HELP MEE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbLxr.png)

```py
from time import sleep
def fill_rect():
    global fill_r
    global fill_v
    global rect_x
    global speed_fill
    fill(fill_r,fill_v,0)
    rect(width/2 - 100, height/2 - 12.5,rect_x,25)
    if rect_x <= 200 - speed_fill :
        rect_x = rect_x + speed_fill
        fill_r = fill_r + 5
        fill_v = fill_v -2
        speed_fill = speed_fill + 1


def setup():
    global fill_r
    global fill_v
    global rect_x
    global speed_fill
    background(0,100,255)
    size(500,500)
    speed_fill = 1
    fill(0)
    rect(width/2 - 100, height/2 - 12.5,200,25)
    rect_x = 1
    fill_r = 25
    fill_v = 100

def draw():
    global fill_r
    global fill_v
    global rect_x
    fill_rect()
```

the loading bar either doesn't go all the way
the sleep import is useless in this code
if i change the parameters of the if statement in the fill_rect() function the loading bar goes beyond the limit

Comment: It's good that you gave us an image of what's bothering you. Don't show code in images, but instead show it in a code block so we can read it easily or copy and paste it.

Comment: i changed it now it should be a bit better

Answer (score 1):

Use [`min`](https://processing.org/reference/min_.html) to limit `rect_x` to the end of the bar:

```py
rect_x = min(200, rect_x + speed_fill)
```

The bar fills up rapidly. The issue is, that the acceleration is to strong:

```py
speed_fill = speed_fill + 1
```

Decrease the acceleration (e.g. 0.1):

```py
def fill_rect():
    global fill_r, fill_v, rect_x, speed_fill

    fill(fill_r, fill_v, 0)
    rect(width/2 - 100, height/2 - 12.5, rect_x, 25)

    if rect_x <= 200:
        rect_x = min(200, rect_x + speed_fill)
        speed_fill += 0.1
        fill_r += 5
        fill_v -= 2
```

[image]

---

Note, the frame rate can be controlled by [`frameRate()`](https://processing.org/reference/frameRate_.html).

Comment: thanks !! isn't there a way to make it accelerate and making it stop at the end of the rectangle??

Comment: @beastmaster64 What do you mean? 1. it accelerates by 0.1 - 2. The function in my answer stops at the end.

Comment: oh! i just realised you changed the if loop's parameters sorry lol

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to make it stop at the end of the rectangle with any acceleration

```
def fill_rect():
    global fill_r
    global fill_v
    global rect_x
    global speed_fill
    fill(fill_r,fill_v,0)
    rect(width/2 - 100, height/2 - 12.5,rect_x,25)
    if rect_x <= 200   :
        if rect_x > 200 - speed_fill:
            rect_x = 200 - speed_fill
        rect_x = rect_x + speed_fill
        fill_r = fill_r + 5
        fill_v = fill_v - 2
        speed_fill = speed_fill + 1
```

Comment: `rect_x = min(200, rect_x + speed_fill)` does exactly the same. See my answer.