# python processing keyPressed() function not working

Tags: python, processing

```
def keyPressed():
    global fill_r
    global fill_v
    global rect_x
    if key == 'W' or key == 'w':
        fill_rect() 
        print("TEST")
```

this is a part of my code that won't work
i did it in processing 3 with python

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the progress bar form your previous question ([How to fix loading bar stopping before the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082221/how-to-fix-loading-bar-stopping-before-the-end)), when <kbd>w</kbd> is pressed, then you have to add a state (`start_progress`). Set the state (`start_progress = True`) when the key is pressed and run `fill_rect` dependent on the state:

```py
from time import sleep

def fill_rect():
    global fill_r, fill_v, rect_x, speed_fill

    fill(fill_r, fill_v, 0)
    rect(width/2 - 100, height/2 - 12.5, rect_x, 25)

    if rect_x <= 200:
        rect_x = min(200, rect_x + speed_fill)
        speed_fill += 1
        fill_r += 5
        fill_v -= 2

def setup():
    global fill_r, fill_v, rect_x, speed_fill, start_progress
    fill_r, fill_v, rect_x, speed_fill = 25, 100, 0, 0
    start_progress = False
    size(500, 500)

def draw():
    background(0, 100, 255)
    fill(0)
    rect(width/2 - 100, height/2 - 12.5, 200, 25)

    if start_progress:
        fill_rect()

def keyPressed():
    global start_progress
    if key == 'W' or key == 'w':
        start_progress = True
        print("TEST")
```